# Self Referencing SQL Query with Calculation

Tags: mysql, sql, self-join

I'm having trouble optimizing a self referencing SQL statement where I need to use data from the table in the selection criteria of a query.

Here is example one using a local variable.

```
SET @target_crit = (SELECT crit from table1 where id = 57)
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE 
(@target_crit + crit > 100) AND 
(@target_crit * critb < 500) AND 
(@target_crit * critc >255)
```

Here is the same example without the local variable but using multiple SELECTS

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE 
((SELECT crit from table1 where id = 57) + crit > 100) AND 
((SELECT crit from table1 where id = 57)* critb < 500) AND 
((SELECT crit from table1 where id = 57)* critc >255)
```

Both work but is there a way to optimize the second query so that all of those SELECT's aren't needed?  Seems like a CROSS JOIN but I'm not joining on specific columns.

This is MySQL and the actual query has 8 calculations in the WHERE clause while the example I have only has 4.  The data table has about 100k records in it.

thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason to have the `sql-server` tag on your question?

Comment: @HABO The reason was to that SO suggested it.  I suppose I shouldn't necessarily had the mysql tag either.  Having both gets a wider audience.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two possibilities for your self join:

```
-- Inner join with filter in join predicate
select *
from table1 as a
    join table1 as b on b.id = 57
where b.crit + a.crit > 100
    and b.crit * a.critb < 500
    and b.crit * a.critc > 255;

-- Cross join with filter in where clause
select *
from table1 as a
    cross join table1 as b
where b.id = 57
    and b.crit + a.crit > 100
    and b.crit * a.critb < 500
    and b.crit * a.critc > 255;
```

Either way, I hope `id` is unique, otherwise you will get "duplicate" rows.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  There was no visible performance difference, both queries came in at 0.006 seconds on a table with 50k records that had to be scanned with the calculations.

Comment: @WesMon glad to hear it. Please upvote and/or mark an answer as correct as appropriate to help future visitors.